# Setting a timeout for a javascript-based service callout

Tags: apigee

We have a callout to another API within a javascript policy:

```
var calloutresponse, status, headers = {
    'key':context.getVariable("request.header.key")
};  
var myRequest = new Request(url, "POST", headers, data);
var exchange = httpClient.send(myRequest);
exchange.waitForComplete();
var calloutResponse = exchange.getResponse();
context.setVariable("calloutstatus",calloutResponse.status.code);
context.setVariable("calloutresponse",calloutResponse.content);
```

There are times when this callout takes an exceptionally long time and we would like to be able to set a timeout limit for it (like one would a target endpoint) and have the calloutResponse.status.code be a 503.
Is there a value which can be set for either the httpClient or Request to set this? I have looked through the Apigee documentation as well as here and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the xml policy that calls the script, there's a `timeLimit` property that defaults to 200ms. You can change this at will.